# ArrayList object overwrites ListView row

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview which lists bluetooth devices, but the listview row gets overwritten each time a bluetooth device is discovered. Am clearing the arraylist object using fetch.clear() method to avoid multiple entries of the same bluetooth device. Placing the fetch.clear() method anywhere else creates multiple entries of same bluetooth device.  How do I stop overwriting the same row in listview?

```
    ArrayList<Custom> fetch = new ArrayList<Custom>();

         btOnOff.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(btOnOff.isChecked()){

            btAdapter.startDiscovery();
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

                bcReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        String action = intent.getAction();
                        if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
                            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                            deviceName = device.getName();
                            currentDateTime = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());

                            fetch.clear(); //clear arraylist object
                            Custom data = new Custom(deviceName, currentDateTime);
                            fetch.add(data);

                            lv.setAdapter(cAdapter);

                        }else if(btAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)){
                            btAdapter.startDiscovery();
                        }
                    }
                };
                IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
                registerReceiver(bcReceiver, filter);
        } else {
            btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: compare and check is already added in list then don't add in list

Comment: Can't you use a `set`[[link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Set.html)] as collection class to avoid duplicate entries?

Comment: invoke notifyDataSetAdapter() of listview.

Answer (score 0):

Use two lists-  one that you send to the Adapter, and one that you fill on each discovery.  When the discovery is done, switch them.  That way it will update only once per discovery.

Comment: Is there a way I can do it using only one list, just I have to stop overwriting the same row, and write newly found device in new row

Comment: invoke notifyDataSetAdapter() of listview